# fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory when using musl-gcc

Tags: musl, synctex

when I using the musl-gcc to compile the synctex https://github.com/jlaurens/synctex project like this:

```
root@f94968c590bb:/home/rust/src/synctex# musl-gcc -c -fPIC *.c
synctex_parser.c:501:25: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
  501 | #               include <zlib.h>
      |                         ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

is it possible to using musl gcc to compile this project? I have already install the dependencies like this:

```
root@f94968c590bb:/home/rust/src/synctex# apt-get install zlib1g-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
zlib1g-dev is already the newest version (1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu9.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
root@f94968c590bb:/home/rust/src/synctex# apt-get install libz-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'zlib1g-dev' instead of 'libz-dev'
zlib1g-dev is already the newest version (1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu9.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
```

this is the version of musl-gcc:

```
root@f94968c590bb:/home/rust/src/synctex# musl-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Reading specs from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-musl/musl-gcc.specs
rename spec cpp_options to old_cpp_options
COLLECT_GCC=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
```

Comment: I marked this question as a duplicate because [its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58249542/2902833) explains exactly what's going on here - musl-gcc doesn't use headers/libraries installed by `apt-get`. You need to compile dependencies manually via musl. That's kind of the whole point of musl, as far as I understand it.

Comment: I'm also not sure why this is tagged `rust` as it doesn't contain anything related to Rust.