# error: first argument to 'va_arg' not of type 'va_list'

Tags: c, musl-gcc

I am compiling the syntex https://github.com/jlaurens/synctex project using musl c in Ubuntu 22.01, now I tried to use the zlib header like this:

```
musl-gcc -c -fPIC *.c -I/usr/include
```

but get this error:

```
In file included from synctex_main.c:76:
/usr/include/stdio.h:52:9: error: unknown type name '__gnuc_va_list'
   52 | typedef __gnuc_va_list va_list;
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdio.h:52:24: error: conflicting types for 'va_list'; have 'int'
   52 | typedef __gnuc_va_list va_list;
      |                        ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-musl/stdarg.h:10,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:36,
                 from synctex_main.c:76:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-musl/bits/alltypes.h:326:27: note: previous declaration of 'va_list' with type 'va_list' {aka '__va_list_tag[1]'}
  326 | typedef __builtin_va_list va_list;
      |                           ^~~~~~~
In file included from synctex_main.c:76:
/usr/include/stdio.h:366:22: error: unknown type name '__gnuc_va_list'
  366 |                      __gnuc_va_list __arg);
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdio.h:371:54: error: unknown type name '__gnuc_va_list'
  371 | extern int vprintf (const char *__restrict __format, __gnuc_va_list __arg);
      |                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdio.h:374:22: error: unknown type name '__gnuc_va_list'
  374 |                      __gnuc_va_list __arg) __THROWNL;
```

is it possible to fixed this error or using musl c to compile the synctex? seems the project was binded with the glibc.

Comment: You're using one compiler to include the internal files of a different compiler. Make sure the directory with your compiler's includes is found before `/usr/include` in the search list. `/usr/include` should be last -- not first -- in the list.

Comment: can you explain more detail? the /usr/include may contains all the C dependencies header. should I specify other header path? @ikegami I am still learning the musl compile.

Comment: Why do you need `-I/usr/include`? That should be the default.

Comment: I am tried to fix this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77228653/fatal-error-zlib-h-no-such-file-or-directory-when-using-musl-gcc @Barmar

Comment: I think you incorrectly fixed that issue. You should be building zlib using musl-gcc, and installing it in paths specific to musl-gcc. In fact, your question was closed as a duplicate of a question whose answer specifically says that. Do not use `-I/usr/include`.